# Consulta usando linq to sql no asp.net MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tenho uma dúvida de como retornar os registros de acordo com a consulta. Não sei o que pode estar errado, mas a consulta não está retornando de acordo com o que foi passado.

Tenho o meu controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //retornar todos os registros  
    sistema_mobileEntities dao = new sistema_mobileEntities();
    TempData["titulo1"] = "Consulta Registro";
    return View(dao.cliente.ToList());

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string recebeNome, int recebeOpcao)
{

    try
    {
        sistema_mobileEntities dao = new sistema_mobileEntities();

        if (recebeOpcao == 1)
        {
            var sql = from c in dao.cliente
                    where SqlMethods.Like(c.nome, recebeNome.Trim() + "%")
                    select c;

            TempData["opcao1"] = "nome";
        }

        if (recebeOpcao == 2)
        {
            var sql = from c in dao.cliente
                      where SqlMethods.Like(c.pai, recebeNome.Trim() + "%")
                      select c;

            TempData["opcao2"] = "pai";
        }

        if (recebeOpcao == 3)
        {
            var sql = from c in dao.cliente
                      where SqlMethods.Like(c.mae, recebeNome.Trim() + "%")
                      select c;

            TempData["opcao3"] = "mae";
        }

        return View(dao.cliente.ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json("Erro ao consultar usuario" + ex.Message);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não está retornando a variável que foi utilizada na busca.

A linha:

```
return View(dao.cliente.ToList());
```

Deveria ser:

```
return View(sql.ToList());
```

Comment: //gera um erro Error The name 'sql' does not exist in the current context 
return View(sql.ToList());

Comment: @itasouza você tem que criar o sql fora do if. `IQueryable<Cliente> sql;`

Comment: Adicionei isso, sem o sql = null me gera outro erro 
IQueryable<cliente> sql;   
sql = null;
deu certo, agradeço!